# Increase of variable for a conversion

Tags: javascript

First of all thanks for help

This is a form

```
<form>

    <span><input type="text" id="from_amount" value="0" name="amount" /></span>
    <select id="convert_from" name="convert_from"></select>
    <span class="into">into</span>
    <span class="num" id="conv_result">0</span>
    <select id="convert_to" name="convert_to" ></select>

    <input type="submit" action="conversions.php?amount=<?=$amount?>&convert_from=<?=$convert_from?>&convert_to=<?=$convert_to?>" method="GET" >
```

I have this variable in javascript, but I want the dollar value increased based the euro.

```
var conversions = {
'euros': {  
    'dollar': 10,
    'yuang': 20
},
values = {
    '0':    '0.00',
    '1':    '0.00',
    '2':    '0.00'

};
var conversion_types = ['credits','dollar', 'yuang'];
```

Here, I convert the content

```
function update_amount() {
var from = conversion_types[parseInt($("#convert_from :selected").val())];
var to = conversion_types[parseInt($("#convert_to :selected").val())];
var data = $("#from_amount").val();
var amount = parseFloat(data.replace(/,/g, ''));

wr(amount * conversions[from][to]);
```

}

How I can do to make it something?

I will do it in PHP that would be something like this, but in javascript.

```
if ($dollar < 100){
    $euros = 10;
}elseif ($dollar > 100) && ($dollar < 200){
    $euros = 20;
}elseif ($dollar > 200){
    $euros = 30;
}
```

I will not do it in javascript.
Thanks you very much.

Comment: It’s really unclear where those values even come from. What does `$dollar` represent? What does `$euros` represent? How do these relate to the `conversions` object above? What else does the `conversions` object contain? Can you [edit] your question, include those details and give an example of how the object should change with the different values?

Comment: So can you explain why the "euros" is a parent for dollar and yuang? And conversions object is missing brackets as I see.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is object so object can call by `.` .Also need to space for `else if` in javascript.

```
var conversions = {
'euros': {  
    'dollar': 10,
    'yuang': 20,
}
};
$dollar = conversions.euros.dollar;
if($dollar < 100){
    $euros = 10;
}else if ($dollar > 100 && $dollar < 200){
    $euros = 20;
}else if ($dollar > 200){
    $euros = 30;
}
console.log($euros);
```